# sails lowers without process.exit - feature or mistake?

Tags: sails.js, pm2, sails-mongo

My sails.js app is running under PM2, and I'd like PM2 to be able to restart the app, which it does in the case of a crash. The thing is, when sails fails to load a hook, for instance, if a DB is not available at startup, then the graceful `sails.lower()` is called internally by sails, but the actual node process does not exit (no `process.exit()` is called after the lowering) by the core sails code. This has the result of PM2 not knowing that sails has shutdown, and therefore not starting it back up again.

This all happens in the initial bootstrapping of the app, and is before any of my code is called, so I have no control over it.

Does anybody have any suggestions of how I may solve this?

I'm thinking I could write a custom core hook that could hook into the `sail.on('lowered', fn)` and call a `process.exit()` on receiving that event. Ideas?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sails doesn't call `process.exit` when it lowers because the Sails app might have been started programmatically (via `sails.lift()` or `sails.lower()`), and exiting the process in this way would quit the script that *called* Sails as well.

The fact is that Node scripts are supposed to exit automatically when there's nothing left in the event loop.  You can verify this yourself by creating a new Sails app with `sails new`, and creating a test script in that directory like:

```
/* testscript.js */
var Sails = require('sails');
Sails.load({hooks: {grunt: false, views: false}}, function(err) {
    console.log('lifted sails!');
    Sails.lower(function(err) {
       console.log('lowered sails!');
    });
});
```

Do `node testscript.js` on the command line and you'll see the two logs, and then the command prompt again.

All this is to demonstrate that if your app is *not* lowering, it's because something is keeping it from doing so.  The most likely thing would be the database adapter.  Some adapters (like Postgres) keep TCP connections alive for awhile.  If you wait 30 seconds or so you'll likely see the process exit automatically.  If 30 seconds is too long to wait, and if you're *not* calling Sails programmatically, you can certainly call `process.exit` yourself.  You can wait for the `lower` event, and then give Sails a bit of time to clean up first:

```
sails.on('lower', function() { 
   // Give Sails five seconds to shut down before pulling the plug.
   setTimeout(
      function() { process.exit(1); },
      5000
   );
});
```

Put that in your `config/bootstrap.js` and you should be good to go.

If you want to find out what's actually hanging your process and preventing it from exiting right now, try the excellent [why-is-node-running](https://github.com/mafintosh/why-is-node-running) module.

> Note: at the time of this posting, the `lower` event is incorrectly documented on Sailsjs.com as `lowered`.  This will be fixed ASAP.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply @sgress454 this makes a lot of sense. I actually wrote a hook to accomplish what I need, and it basically what you suggested, although, as it's the ORM hook that is failing (when a DB is offline for instance), my bootstrap.js code doesn't ever get run.

Answer (score 2):

I've ended up writing a hook to accomplish what I need. The hook listens for the `sails.on('lower')` (not 'lowered' as the documentation says!!) and waits a configurable time then calls a `process.exit()` with a configurable exit code.

If anyone else needs it, create the follwoing `api/hooks/exitOnLower.js` file...

```
module.exports = function (sails) {

    return {
        defaults: {
            __configKey__: {
                name  : 'exitOnlower',
                wait  : 10000,
                active: true,
                // exitCode : 2
            }
        },

        initialize: function (cb) {

            var active   = sails.config[this.configKey].active;
            var timeout  = sails.config[this.configKey].wait;
            var exitCode = sails.config[this.configKey].exitCode;

            if (!active) {
                return cb();
            }

            sails.on('lower', function () {
                sails.log.verbose("[hook:killOnLower] Sails lower detected, exiting in %sms...", timeout);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    sails.log.warn("[hook:killOnLower] exiting app");
                    process.exit(exitCode ? exitCode : null);
                }, timeout)
            });

            return cb();
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: I was having the exact same problem and this worked like a charm!